# How to show all dates on xAxis between two dates in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[Current chart img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeQsV.png)

I have a little issues with my chart, how to display all dates on xAxis between two given dates?
I can't display all dates, on screen each 2nd month is skipped.
I tried different options.

My current options settings:

```js
scales: {
    xAxes: [
        { 
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
            },
            type: "time",
            time: {
                unit: window.unit,
                min: window.minDate,
                max: window.maxDate,
                parser: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss",
                displayFormats: {
                    day: "DD.MM",
                    month: "MMMM",
                    week: "DD.MM",
                },
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

[source: "labels" example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Ovb.png)
its show all dates, but with duplicates i need just one dates from per month.

[distribution: "series" example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWA02.png)

Also i used ticks min and max  - its didnt work.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way.

```js
  scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            maxTicksLimit: 31, 
                            maxRotation: 90, 
                            minRotation: 45,              
                        },
                        type: "time",
                        time: {
                            min: window.minDate,
                            max: window.maxDate,
                            parser: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss",
                            unit: window.unit,
                            displayFormats: {
                                day: "DD.MM",
                                month: "MMMM",
                                week: "DD.MM",
                            },
                            display: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
```

But now you need to stretch the line of the graph from the beginning to the end
[img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiGmA.png)